# Is it possible to fully replace a Linux device tree at runtime?

Tags: linux, arm, device-tree

so I know about device tree overlays and how to apply them via `of_overlay_fdt_apply`.

However, for a research project I want to change huge chunks of the fdt at runtime, so I was wondering if there is any inbuilt functionality of the kernel that allows you to just replace the entire device tree with another blob at runtime.

I know that replacing a device tree would be really complicated from the kernel perspective, but since as far as I know Linux even supports stuff like CPU-hotplugging this wouldn't be too far off.

Comment: Could you please explain why resetting your system and booting using NFS would not work in your case ?

Comment: Your comparison with CPU hotplugging is probably irrelevant. The Device Tree is primarily used at boot time to initialize the system, especially device drivers. Before the rootfs is mounted as one of the last steps in kernel booting, the `__init` section of code and data is released. So you might be able to "*replace*" the DT, but you still have to get the kernel to reconfigure itself (as well as reinitialize the hardware) with that new configuration. IMO that is beyond the scope and capability of an already-running system.